# The charts on the civicontribute dashboard do not display

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

Trying to figure out why the charts on the my WordPress / CiviCRM 4.7.27 CiviContribute dashboard are not displaying. We see no errors on the front end, but no charts appear.

Anybody have any good ideas on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 5):

This is usually because of flash player not allowing to load on all sites. I added the site in allowed section for flash. Here is what i did

1. Navigate to Chrome settings >> Privacy and Security >> Content Settings >> Flash.
2. Add site url under allow section.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: They do not show up on the dashboard in either chrome or safari. The demo looks the same as on my build.

Comment: I have updated my original answer. Let me know how it goes.