# CiviReport's and CiviContribute Charts not displaying

Tags: wordpress, civireport, chart

We are using civi 5.3 on Wordpress 4.9.
Using CiviReports or CiviContribute, I am selecting Charts, and clicking the view button.  The chart is not loading.   I saw the other answers suggesting that I enable flash in chrome for this site, but this is happening on Chrome, Explorer and Safari. Could the paths for these graphs be wrong?  Where would I check that?
The charts have never worked for us, even before upgrading to 5.3.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers don't show up flash chart by default, you will need allow flash for certain urls or make it allow for all sites. This [answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21955/155) might be useful to fix your problem.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Which browsers do allow it?  I used Chrome, Explorer and Safari. I think it's safe to assume Fire Fox doesn't allow it by default either.   It would appear that none allow it by default.  I would think the solution is Civi should not be relying on flash to display the charts if you are indeed pinpointing the issue.

Comment: And you are correct, as it works after I enabled flash for this site in chrome.  The problem is I now have to explain that to several internet illiterate people who need to see those charts.